# Doing ranking in ListView .vb

Tags: vb.net, sorting, ranking

What should I do to call the Username and the Scores codes from 2 different form to run it in my ranking form and how to use SORT to do the ranking.

[Username form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOuys.png)

[Scores form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z5dU.png)

[Ranking form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKEO9.png)

Comment: Your question is far too vague.  You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of exactly what you want to achieve, exactly how you're attempting to achieve it and exactly where you're stuck.  More words, more detail and more code are required.  If you have no code, it's too soon to post a question here.

Comment: @Chloe Burke Please refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Just call it like this:

```
Yourform.textbox.text
```

or

```
Yourform.label.text
```

And add it to your ListView by `YourListViewName.items.add(Yourform.textbox.text , Yourform.label.text)`